# Error while getting libraries name using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am executing the below script to get all libraries name in subsite:

```
Get-SPweb http://server:80/sites/sitename/subsitename |
   Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
   Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" } |
    Select Title
```

I am getting error:
Cannot find an SPWeb object with id or url :......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall the reason, but I had also faced this problem and the solution was to first create SPSite object and use it in get-spweb.

```
$siteURL = "http://server:80/sites/sitename"
$webURL = "/subsitename"
$site = get-spsite $siteURL
get-spweb -site $site $webURL
```