# Copy documents from one document library to another using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using below Powershell script to copy contents from one document library to another, however I am getting this error:

```
Cannot find an SPWeb object with id or url :......
```

Script:

```
$ver = $host | select version
if($Ver.version.major -gt 1) {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"}
if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0))
{
Write-Progress -Activity "Loading Modules" -Status "Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

##
#Set Static Variables
##

$SourceWebURL = "http://servername/sites/sitename/subsitename"
$SourceLibraryTitle = "testing"
$DestinationWebURL = "http://servername/sites/sitename/archivesubsitename"
$DestinationLibraryTitle = "archive"

##
#Begin Script
##

$sWeb = Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL
$sList = $sWeb.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq $SourceLibraryTitle}
$dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL
$dList = $dWeb.Lists | ? {$_.title -like $DestinationLibraryTitle}

$AllFolders = $sList.Folders
$RootFolder = $sList.RootFolder
$RootItems = $RootFolder.files

foreach($RootItem in $RootItems)
{
    $sBytes = $RootItem.OpenBinary()
    $dFile = $dList.RootFolder.Files.Add($RootItem.Name, $sBytes, $true)

    $AllFields = $RootItem.Item.Fields | ? {!($_.sealed)}

    foreach($Field in $AllFields)
    {
        if($RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title])
        {
            if(!($dFile.Properties[$Field.title]))
            {
                $dFile.AddProperty($Field.Title, $RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title])
            }
            else
            {
                $dFile.Properties[$Field.Title] = $RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title]
            }
        }
    }
    $dFile.Update()
}

foreach($Folder in $AllFolders)
{
    Remove-Variable ParentFolderURL
    $i = 0

    $FolderURL = $Folder.url.Split("/")

    while($i -lt ($FolderURL.count-1))
    {
    $ParentFolderURL = "$ParentFolderURL/" + $FolderURL[$i]
    $i++
    }

    $CurrentFolder = $dList.Folders | ? {$_.url -eq $ParentFolderURL.substring(1)}
    if(!($CurrentFolder.Folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Folder.Name}))
    {
        $NewFolder = $dlist.Folders.Add(("$DestinationWebURL" + $ParentFolderURL), [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, $Folder.name)
        $NewFolder.update()
    }
    else
    {
        $NewFolder = $dList.Folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Folder.Name}
    }
    $AllFiles = $sList.Items
    $sItems = $Folder.folder.Files

    if($Folder.Folder.Files.count -gt 0)
    {
        foreach($item in $sItems)
        {

            $Relative = ($Item.ServerRelativeUrl).substring(1)
            $TargetItem = $AllFiles | ? {$_.URL -eq $Relative}
            $sBytes = $TargetItem.File.OpenBinary()
            $dFile = $Newfolder.Folder.Files.Add($TargetItem.Name, $sBytes, $true)
            $AllFields = $TargetItem.Fields | ? {!($_.sealed)}

            foreach($Field in $AllFields)
            {
                if($TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title])
                {
                    if(!($dFile.Properties[$Field.title]))
                    {
                        $dFile.AddProperty($Field.Title, $TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title])
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $dFile.Properties[$Field.Title] = $TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title]
                    }
                }
            }
            $dFile.Update()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it different than your earlier question [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129292/error-while-getting-libraries-name-using-powershell-script](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129292/error-while-getting-libraries-name-using-powershell-script)?

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing correct url of the site? Open the subsite from browser and get hold of the url which is created. This error happens if you pass wrong url to `Get-SPWeb`

Comment: @VivekAthalye: yes it is different Earlier was different script.
NadeemYousuf: yes both urls are opening in browser

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if the Url of the sub site is correct. The PS command `$sWeb = Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL` should work. Since it isn't working for you, there is another way you can try it:

```
    $siteCollectionUrl = 'http://servername/sites/sitename'
    $site = Get-SPSite $siteCollectionUrl
    $web = $site.OpenWeb('subsitename')
```